# switching between viewControllers

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I've used this method on several apps that are for sale on the app store, but for some reason the current app I am working on is driving me nuts... I must be overlooking something.

**The app's main viewController .h file:**

```
#import "MainMenuController.h"
#import "GamePlay.h"

@interface ProjectNameiPhoneViewController : UIViewController <MenuDelegate, GameDelegate> {
      UIViewController *currentPageController;
}
```

**The app starts up and loads the MainMenu viewController:**

```
UIViewController *nextController = [[MainMenuController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuController" bundle:nil];
[nextController performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self];

[self.view addSubview:nextController.view];

currentPageController = nextController;
[currentPageController retain];
[nextController release];
```

**From MainMenuController.m, the user chooses to start the game:**

```
[delegate startGameplay:self];
```

**Back in the app's main viewController:**

```
- (void)startGameplay:(MainMenuController *)sender {

    UIViewController *nextController = [[GamePlay alloc] initWithNibName:@"GamePlay" bundle:nil];

    [nextController performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self];

    [currentPageController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:nextController.view];

    [currentPageController release];
    currentPageController = nextController;
    [currentPageController retain];
    [nextController release];
}
```

**From the gameplay screen, user hits the back button to return to the main menu:**

```
- (IBAction)backTapped {
    [delegate backToMenu:self];
}
```

**Back in the app's main viewController:**

```
- (void)backToMenu:(GamePlay *)sender {

    UIViewController *nextController = [[MainMenuController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuController" bundle:nil];

    [nextController performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self];

    [currentPageController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:nextController.view];

    [currentPageController release];
    currentPageController = nextController;
    [currentPageController retain];
    [nextController release];   
}
```

I once again choose to start the game from the main menu.

The GamePlay class/Nib loads, and I once again click the back button to return to the main menu.

**At this point the app crashes, with no information printed to the console.**

Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated - I've commented out almost everything else in my code to the point where this switching between viewControllers is practically the only code being run and I'm at a loss as to why it is crashing...

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Enable zombie and check reason for the crash.

Comment: I just enabled zombies and still no message prints to the console when the app crashes...

Comment: Thanks woody, but I have my rootViewController launch a MainMenuController in all of my apps... my rootViewController just acts as the delegate that switches back and forth between the different views, from MainMenu to GamePlay to Credits and other views

Comment: Debug the method backToMenu for each line of code and check the objects allocation.

Comment: This now works perfectly in the Simulator, works well on an iPhone 4S with iOS 5, and crashes consistently on an iPad (1st gen) running iOS 5. Frustrating!  =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a true resolution but the app only crashes when I'm running it through Xcode's "build and run." If I open the app by clicking the icon on the device itself, the app runs perfectly. I can play it for long periods of time and mash the buttons to switch between view controllers over and over again very quickly, and it does not crash. So I'm going to submit it for the App Store even though it crashes every time without an error message when running through Xcode - it absolutely does not crash on the device itself.

The strangest part about the crash when running through Xcode is this:
The app crashes on the device, exiting out to the home screen. However, Xcode still shows the app as "Running" and I have the option to click "Stop" - it is not grayed out. As I said, no error message is printed to the console.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you want to have the MainMenuController as the rootViewController of your application's keyWindow.

Additionally, UIViewController's views should not be added to other UIViewController's views as this breaks the responder chain and in iOS 5.0, will throw an exception. If you choose to only implement it as an iOS 5.0 application, then I recommend taking a look at `[UIViewController -addChildViewController:]` and `[UIViewController -removeChildViewController:]`

In saying this, a better solution if doable, would be to have the MainMenuController as the rootViewController as stated above, and then to call `[UIViewController -presentModalViewController:animated:]` in your `startGameplay` method and use the delegate to dismiss the modal view controller

Comment: Thanks again for your response - I am definitely wondering if the problem has anything to do with either iOS 5 or XCode 4.2 as I had no issues with this prior to iOS 5...   I will look into "addChildViewController" and "removeChildViewController" - are you saying those are ONLY to be used with iOS 5 and not with prior OS versions?

Comment: and addSubview / removeFromSuperview are newly NOT allowed in iOS 5.0?

Comment: You continue to use addSubview and removeFromSuperview, but to keep the UIResponder chain intact, addChildViewController/removeChildViewController are used. This means that rotation and similar events are passed correctly down the chain.

Comment: Nesting view controllers like this was also discouraged and violated some of UIViewControllers stated assumptions under iOS 4 and earlier. It shouldn't be too surprising that use of this approach causes unexpected behavior under iOS 5. I tried to explain this here: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/ if that's any help.